# Where can I purchase a keyboard waffle-maker like the one on the Meta 404 page?

Tags: discussion, waffles, keyboard, 404-not-found

Where can I find one of those cool keyboard waffle-makers like the one on the [Meta 404 page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/waffle-iron)?

[image: WAFFLE]

I'm interested in possibly getting one for myself.

Comment: Kickstarter campaign for the Keyboard Waffle Iron is coming very soon! Follow us @KeyboardWaffles

Comment: Zach, as of today (12/24/2014), "Kickstarter" (an org that raises funds to assist projects) has raised $62k+ toward the goal of $50K to see this neat idea become a product we all may buy in the future. Check it out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, you might. It was recently [a Kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1304060422/the-keyboard-waffle-iron/) that was fully funded.

See also:

- [thekeyboardwaffleiron.com](http://www.thekeyboardwaffleiron.com/)
- [Re/code: Keyboard Waffle Iron Sells Like Hotcakes, Surpasses Kickstarter Goal](http://recode.net/2014/12/26/keyboard-waffle-iron-sells-like-hotcakes-surpasses-kickstarter-goal/)

Answer (score 17):

You can't.

> It was created by Chris Dimino as part of a project that involved breathing new life into a now useless product by giving it another purpose. In this case the ‘useless product’ was an old Corona typewriter that was reborn as the Corona-Matic which makes keyboard shaped waffles.

http://www.designhead.net/cdimino/typewriters4.html
http://www.engadget.com/2007/05/03/keyboard-waffle-iron-cooks-up-your-favorite-peripheral/
http://gizmodo.com/257153/the-keyboard-waffle-iron
http://zedomax.com/blog/2008/06/11/keyboard-waffle-maker/

Comment: Too bad...I guess I'll have to see if I can make one myself, then.

Comment: @Zach: seems so :S