# Should [waffles] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, waffles

I don't get the point of [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles). Nearly all posts with that tag are humorous and unnecessary or necessary, constructive, but [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) have nothing to do with them. Also, from their tag wiki: `Waffles are supreme. That is all.`

Comment: See [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480)

Comment: What kind of monster burns waffles?

Comment: And there even [legitimate uses of the tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138012/no-more-waffles). But mostly, because *fun is allowed here*. Lets not destroy that culture.

Comment: @TimStone inexperienced cooks, who just don't know how to make it right?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FQBaI.png

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait; what? **Fun** is allowed here, and no one told me!?!?! (And by 'here', you mean "The Stack Exchange Network", right?)

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Yay! Beautiful forest, isn't it? ‌​‌​           

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Legitimate uses"? So now we have a tag over every users' name?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet: I present to you: [The keyboard-waffle-maker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46916/where-can-i-purchase-a-keyboard-waffle-maker-like-the-one-on-the-meta-404-page).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Waffles shall never be burninated, because they stand for all that is lovely and delicious, and without them, MSO would not be lovely (or delicious).

If you didn't know this yet, SE's servers run on waffles. Tons of them, every day, are swallowed up via the disk drives into the servers, where they are converted into webpages like this very one. Waffles are vital to this website.

Seriously, though, it's the fun part of SE that many of us are working hard to create that is what the waffles tag stands for. Although some fun may be inappropriate, the waffles tag is harmless and isn't hurting anyone. So just roll with it- if you don't like waffles, don't worry about it. They don't really like you either.