# Where do I put these [waffles]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, waffles, usage

I've never fully understood the [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) tag. About half of the tag's current questions seem to have nothing to do with waffles per se, but seem to include the tag as a point or humor or whimsy. The tag's tag wiki is unclear ("Waffles are supreme. That is all."), but a request in 2014 to burninate the tag was [poorly-received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234451/336163).

In what cases does the tag [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) belong on a question on Meta Stack Exchange? To be clear, I'm not asking for a burnination (you can support the existing burninate request if you wish), but asking for tag usage. That is, *if we are not going to burninate the tag, then when exactly should it be used and when should it not be used*? Is it a generic "fun" tag that I can add liberally to questions that I feel are fun or funny, or does it (or should it) have a specific non-obvious meaning?

Comment: There are **72 answers** here, so calling it a duplicate would get lost, but I think that [the cryptic answer is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/282094); under "[The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/282094)" (page 3, Active tab).

Answer (score 7):

This is a "fun tag", that is no longer used, and should not be used in new questions.

**However**, I think we should keep it where it was used and not remove it, in honor of [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/17174/waffles), who has major part in making Stack Overflow what it is today. (The good parts of it.)

Consider this tag as "brother tag" of [jeff-atwood](/questions/tagged/jeff-atwood).